# kableExtra::column_spec() returns undefined control sequence when rendering notebooks in a loop with rmarkdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I use knitr in an R markdown document to create table in a pdf report. A column contains lengthy product description which I usually wrap. For some reason the latex compilation started returning an error.

[UPDATE] rendering it once works succesfully, but rendering the notebook a second time causes the error. My real use case is a a loop within which I render the same notebook several time for different product groups. Similar to [the use case described in bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-render.html) where a report is rendered "for each state of a country".

## Reproducible example that fails to render a pdf document

File `/tmp/notebook.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Test document"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup}
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
iris %>%
    knitr::kable(format="latex") %>%
    kableExtra::column_spec(2, width = "10em")
```
````

Compiling the file to a pdf document with the R command:

```
rmarkdown::render("notebook.Rmd")
```

[Update]: Run the render command a second time to see the error.

Returns the error

```
/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS notebook.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output notebook.tex --lua-filter /home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'
[WARNING] Deprecated: --self-contained. use --embed-resources --standalone
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> r|>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash
                          s                 }p{10em}|r|r|l
l.117 ...\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{10em}|r|r|l}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile notebook.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See notebook.log for more info.
```

## Rendering to html works fine

````
---
title: "Test document"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
iris %>%
    knitr::kable(format="html") %>%
    kableExtra::column_spec(2, width = "10em")
```
````

This renders without an error.

Comment: I see different behaviour:  it works when I click Knit in RStudio every time, but never works when I run `rmarkdown::render()`.  Clearly a bug somewhere, but I can't spot where...

Comment: @user2554330 do you get the same latex compilation error?

Comment: According to [rmarkdown-cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html) "When you click the Knit button in RStudio, it will call the rmarkdown::render() function in a new R session"

Comment: Yes, I get a complaint about `\arraybackslash`.  (I don't have an "s" on the next line, just blanks.)  Apparently the cookbook is wrong, it looks as though `Knit` adds something extra to the `render()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me in RStudio when I click `Knit`, but not when I run `rmarkdown::render("notebook.Rmd")` as you did.  After some playing around to see what the difference is (specifically I asked for a `latex_document` instead of a `pdf_document` so I could see the tex code), I found that the `Knit` button adds a whole lot of extra dependencies that aren't there in the `rmarkdown::render()` call.

I think I understand why this sometimes worked for you.  `kableExtra` sets all the extra dependencies when it is loaded, but only if it is loaded during a `knitr` LaTeX run.  So the first time you run it, it would work, but the second time, it was already loaded, so it didn't set those dependencies.  They need to be set during the run, they won't carry over from the previous run.

So a workaround is to unload `kableExtra` before calling `rmarkdown::render()`.  That way it will be loaded during the processing of your document, and things should be fine.  Do this by

```
unloadNamespace("kableExtra")
rmarkdown::render("notebook.Rmd")
```

The `unloadNamespace("kableExtra")` line can also be put into the document itself before the first use of `kableExtra`, e.g.

````
---
title: "Test document"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup}
library(dplyr)
unloadNamespace("kableExtra")
```

```{r}
iris %>%
    knitr::kable(format="latex") %>%
    kableExtra::column_spec(2, width = "10em")
```
````

Comment: Adding `extra_dependencies: array` to the yaml metadata doesn't fix the issue. Running `unloadNamespace("kableExtra")` before the second render, does fix the issue. I see that someone already reported this at [kableExtra issue 721](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/721).

Comment: I've removed the suggestion that didn't work for you.